# How to show status bar notification using Cordova - Android and IOS

Tags: android, cordova, push-notification, cordova-plugins, statusbar

I read through many blogs and Stackoverflow threads regarding Status bar notification and most of the blog uses a plugin https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/StatusBarNotification

But this gives 404 error. I didn't find any other valid plugin to do this.

I need to get this following code to work. What plugin do I need to use ?

```
window.plugins.statusBarNotification.notify("Notification", "Registered with Server");
```

Thanks

Comment: Try reporting broken link to the demo sites you are referring.

Comment: All the blogs which posts content about Status Bar notification with Cordova have the same link. Am searching for any other available way. It would be helpful if I get a way to install StatusBarNotification plugin or any other workaround.

Comment: Please update question with the blogs you're referring.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-statusbar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved my issue with the following plugin and code snippet.

[de.appplant.cordova.plugin.local-notification](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications)

```
cordova.plugins.notification.local.schedule({
    id: 1,
    title: "Production Jour fixe",
    text: "Duration 1h",
    firstAt: monday_9_am,
    every: "week",
    sound: "file://sounds/reminder.mp3",
    icon: "http://icons.com/?cal_id=1",
    data: { meetingId:"123#fg8" }
});

cordova.plugins.notification.local.on("click", function (notification) {
    joinMeeting(notification.data.meetingId);
});
```

Thanks.

Comment: THANKS! I was looking for the same, and helped by your own answer above - appreciate it. Somehow many responders misunderstood what we needed, that is: How to show local notification on the DEVICE statusbar (not on app's statusbar).

Answer (score 0):

The link you are looking for has been moved to a different location , here -->[StatusBarNotification](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/DEPRECATED/Android/StatusBarNotification) which is deprecated

So as per your updated answer, you are using the proper plugin.

Comment: I think above response should be in comment but I cannot do it directly without answering , so I had to add it as an answer

Answer (score 0):

I made a plugin based on CWStatusBarNotification for iOS if you want yo can use it 
[CordovaStatusBarNotification](https://github.com/jorgemejia/CordovaStatusBarNotification)